# Retrieve the value of an array at a specific index that is a property of an object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering if there is a more compact/better way writing PowerShell commands to retrieve the information I'm looking forward.

I have an object that contains a property that is an array, of type string, and I want to get the second item. I can do this now by executing either of following commands:

```
$object | Select-Property -Property @{Name="Title";Expression={$_.Property[1]}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Title

($object | Select-Property -Property @{Name="Title";Expression={$_.Property[1]}}).Title
```

They both work just fine but, as you can see, it's a lot of typing and I get the feeling that I'm going about this in a round about manner. I'd like to be able to retrieve $_.Property[1] and expand it in the same Select-Object commandlet statement.

Comment: `$object.Property[1]`? BTW, do you mean `Select-Object` instead of `Select-Property`?

Comment: Yes, that worked and yes, I did mean `Select-Object`. Thanks for your help. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are going for?

`$object | % {$_.title}`

Is the object an array or a hash table?

If HashTable, then the elements are actually key-value pairs.  If you type `$object | gm` do you see some properties called **`keys`** and **`values`**?

`$object['Title']`

and

`$object['Expression']`